# Passing id of an object through an onclick function of jquery in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one Controller `VendorController`. And view file is `index.html.erb`

I want to pass the id of vendor through onclick function.
Here is my code

Codes under `vendors_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @vendor = Vendor.all
end
```

Codes of `index.html.erb`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function func1(id) {
    alert(_id);
}

function func2(id) {
    alert(id);
}
</script>


<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=link_to vendor.name , '#',  onclick: "func1(1)", remote: true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to vendor.id, '#', :onclick => 'func2(vendor.id)' %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

For `func1()` i am getting the alert. But for `func2` I am not getting any response.
Please help..thank you in advance.

Comment: Your javascript isn't in a javascript tag, and you reference `_id` instead of `id` in the first function.

Comment: ya its under javascript tag only ... k I am updating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to escape the contents of your onclick to have the actual id in it, instead of just a string saying "vendor.id" - remember it's just a string, so it needs to have the right data in it when it gets loaded in the browser.

Try

```
<td><%= link_to vendor.id, '#', :onclick => "func2(#{vendor.id})" %></td>
```

Note double quotes, to allow string interpolation.

Comment: And what happens?  Any javascript errors?  Anything at all?

Comment: in console `vendor is not defined`

Comment: I'd expect that since vendor is a variable in rails, not in javascript.  You do understand that this html and javascript is **generated** on the server, but **runs** in the browser right?

Comment: erb tags like this `<%= link_to vendor.id, '#', :onclick => "func2(#{vendor.id})" %>` are evaluated (aka rendered) on your server, in rails, to make a static page of text to send back to the browser.  The browser then runs this page.  So `vendor` in the above example is a variable in rails, on the server.  The generated text will be something like `<a href="#" onclick="func2(123)">123</a>`.  `vendor` is not defined anywhere on the resulting page of text and so cannot possibly be referenced by any javascript.

Comment: That's referencing my answer by the way (which should work), rather than your broken question.

Comment: thank u very much ... its working now . I have written my codes like this `func2("#{vendor.id}")`. Now its working fine

Comment: Does that mean that when you said "no i have tried that" you actually hadn't tried it?

Comment: u told me to do `"func2(#{vendor.id})"`

Comment: but i did this `func2("#{vendor.id}")` .. why should i tell lie. I was facing some problems thats wy I have asked this question right ?

Comment: Oh i see - you're passing it as a string to the function and i was passing it as an integer.  I beg your pardon.  The alert should work either way, ie the func2 you provided would work the same with either a string or integer.  Was there other code in your "real" function which you didn't include in the question.

Comment: No.. i have included every thing. Its ok .. its solved now. Thanks again. because from You I got the idea of using interpolation here.

Comment: And i still don't understand why the code in my answer wouldn't make the alert fire.

Answer (score 10):

@max-williams answer should solve your problem.  But I'd also recommend that you explore the option of embedding the record ID in the `<tr>` tag as a data attribute instead of writing out the `onclick` function.  Then in your JS, you can dynamically select the ID in your event listeners.

Consider:

```
<tr data-id="<%= vendor.id %>">
  <td><%= link_to vendor.id, '#', :class=>"vendor-link" %></td>
</tr>
```

Then just listen for clicks:

```
$( ".vendor-link" ).click(function() {
  id = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
  alert(id);
});
```

This method will separate out your JS from your HTML template and make it a little more manageable.  Plus, you can also attach multiple click functions, giving you a little more flexibility.

Comment: This is true, it's nicer to not have onclick attributes in your template code, and instead collect all of your JS together.