# Javascript inside Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have a ruby each method below that has a button onclick embedded in it that I am trying to get to make a call to iex's stats api for each stock inside the portfolio when the ticker is clicked and store that in a table i have built. Here is the ruby:

```
<% portfolio.assignments.each_with_index do |a, index|%>
   <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div>
     <div id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
       <button onclick="getStock();" class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree<%=a.id%>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree<%=a.id%>">                                    
        <li class="list-inline-item"id="<%=a.stock.ticker%>"><%= a.stock.ticker %></li>
```

parts of the code is missing but i just included the parts that i thought were relevant but when i run the code and inspect it in the browser i can see that everything is loading correctly for each ticker stored in the db but it only shows the data return for the first ticker?

```
function getStock() {
 $('#<%=a.stock.ticker%>').each(function(){
  var theURL = `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/<%=a.stock.ticker%>/stats`;
   $.getJSON(theURL, function(data) {
     var obj = data;
      document.getElementById("symbol").innerHTML = obj.symbol;
  });
 })
};
```

here is part of the table i have:

```
<table class="table table-hover text-left">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th>Symbol:</th>
        <td id="symbol"></td>
```

Comment: You can only have one element with a given `id` on each HTML page. Maybe use a class instead.

Comment: I meant to say the last ticker in the original comment. It is still does this when I updated the getStock() function. It only returns the last ticker

Answer (score 1):

You have `n` assignments and by `each_with_index`, you will get `n` numbers of `div` calling `getStock()` for `n` number of times.

But actual problem is your JavaScript function `getStock()` is single copy and it is not repeated to find each assignment ticker for a loop.

Just replace following,

```
"getStock();"
```

with,

```
"getStock(#{a.stock.ticker});"
```

And modify function as,

```
function getStock(ticker) {
 $(ticker).each(function(){
  var theURL = `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/' + ticker + '/stats`;
   $.getJSON(theURL, function(data) {
     var obj = data;
      document.getElementById("symbol").innerHTML = obj.symbol;
  });
 })
};
```

**Update** - In case above does not work, you may try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700747/10522579) & update function.

Comment: this isn't working when I add the above `getStock(#{a.stock.ticker});` to the button element it throws a syntax error

Comment: @JosephParker My bad, I did not tested but there is solution I added in update (to avoid repetition) in my answer. :)